# make - Only create intermediate files if needed

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a Makefile to build a Latex document depending on plots whose data is generated from some other data by some python script.

It looks like this

```
% pdf plot needed by final document
build/tikz-standalone/%.pdf: build/tikz-standalone/%.tex xy_data
    cd $$(dirname $@) && ../../latexrun $$(basename $<)

xy_data: $(PLOT_DATA) tools/plots/crunch.py | build
    % crunch.py will create data for plots needed by build/tikz-standalone/%.tex
    PYTHONPATH=. tools/plots/crunch.py

build:
    mkdir -p build build/other_stuff ...
```

`crunch.py` generates several data files in `build/data` which are needed by `build/tikz-standalone/%.tex`. To create these files it uses other files stored in the variable `PLOT_DATA`. I could put a list of the intermediate data files in `build/data` into the Makefile at the position of `xy_data`. I don't like this as this would require me to update the list whenever a new file is added. What I want is that all data files are recreated whenever `crunch.py` or `$(PLOT_DATA)` has changed.

Is there a way to express this in Make?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to provide and maintain the list of the generated files you can turn your (implicitly) phony `xy_data` target into an empty file used as a marker. Simply touch it at the end of the recipe:

```
BUILDDIRS := build build/other_stuff ...

build/tikz-standalone/%.pdf: build/tikz-standalone/%.tex xy_data
    cd $(dir $@) && ../../latexrun $(notdir $<)

xy_data: $(PLOT_DATA) tools/plots/crunch.py | $(BUILDDIRS)
    PYTHONPATH=. tools/plots/crunch.py
    touch $@

$(BUILDDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Note: I also improved a bit some other aspects:

1. Use of make functions `dir` and `notdir` instead of the shell equivalents.
2. Variable declaration for the build directories to avoid writing the same list several times, which is tedious and error prone.
3. Explicit list of all build directories as order-only prerequisites instead of just one, which could lead to unexpected results if this single one exists but not some others.
4. Generic rule for all build directories thanks to the `$@` automatic variable.